# Questions on generating random numbers on thrust::device_vector

Tags: cuda, thrust

Currently I am using following codes to generate random normal numbers:

```
#include <thrust/random/normal_distribution.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class genNormal
{
private:
    thrust::minstd_rand rng;
    thrust::random::normal_distribution<T> dist;

public:
    genNormal()               :dist(0.0, 1.0){} // default  mean=0, st.dev.=1.0
    genNormal(T mean, T stdev):dist(mean,stdev){} // specific mean and standard deviation

    __host__ __device__
        T operator()(uint64_t index)
    {
        rng.discard(index);
        return dist(rng);
    }
};

void main() {
    thrust::device_vector<double> r1(10);
    for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
       thrust::transform(thrust::make_counting_iterator<int>(0), thrust::make_counting_iterator<int>(10),r1.begin(),genNormal<double>(5.074469, 0.04385328));
       cout<<r1[1]<<", ";   
    }
}
```

Output I got is:

```
5.0143, 5.0143, 5.0143, 5.0143, 5.0143,
```

The problem here is that for each loop I get exactly the same result. What if I need different numbers? In C++11 I could use a random device as seed passing to random engine. However, I didn't find any substitute in thrust library.

Could Anyone help on this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the duplicate provided by talonmies (code is similar to yours): "Note that in order to have a different vector each time you call the transform operation, you should use a counting iterator initialised to a different starting value."

Comment: You can also pass a seed directly to `rng`, perhaps as a third initializing parameter to your functor `genNormal`.  For example, add another prototype: `genNormal(T mean, T stdev, T seed):dist(mean,stdev), rng(seed){} // specific mean, stddev and seed` and then pass a 3rd parameter (perhaps `i`) to your functor in the `thrust::transform` call.